# Rename the file name using shell prefer sed cut command and awk

Tags: python, shell, awk, sed, cut

I want to rename the file name like below mentioned

If the file name is abc_test_tt_3447.txt i want 
abc_tt_3447.txt

If the file name is abc_test_ff_tt_3447.txt i want 
abc_tt_3447.txt

If I want replace the test and test_ff with empty

I have tried with sed command

Comment: Do you have multiple files named like your example and you want to rename them all?

Comment: Yes Multiple file and test is an example i can say I don't want second and third words in the file name but both actions perform at the  same step with different files

Answer (score 0):

with bash either:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *_test*; do
    echo mv -- "$file" "${file//_test?(_ff)/}""
done
```

or:

```
for file in *_test*; do
    [[ $file =~ (.*)_test(_ff)?(.*) ]] &&
    echo mv -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when done testing.